# HTML, CSS issue: HTML fieldset placing/positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a HTML page with personal information details using text boxes. I have two fieldsets as in

[**this Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XdRYT/).

As noticed that the fieldsets are placed up and down position. My question is that

**How can I placed these two fieldsets side by side (left & right position)?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the form `width: 40%;` and assigned a `float:left;` property on those fieldsets. Here is the corrected fiddle: [Try me](http://jsfiddle.net/XdRYT/7/)

Answer (score 4):

Remove `width:40%` from `form` & give `float` to your `fieldsets`.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/XdRYT/8/

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is create table with two cells and one row and place each fieldset in different cell. Another bit more complicated is to use CSS to format it.

Comment: As of May 2012, there shouldn't be any reason to use tables for placing elements on a page. CSS, no matter how complicated it might seem, is the only correct way to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Change fieldset stye to below

```
  fieldset {
            border: 1px dotted #61B5CF;
            margin-top: 1.4em;
            padding: 0.6em;
            float:left;
            width:40%;
           }
```